# Mapping multiple source fields to a Multi-line textbox target field

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I'm trying to map multiple address fields from my source (i.e. address 1, City, State, Zip) into a target field which is a multi-line textbox.

[image]

I'm using the OOTB "Collection to String Value" reader as the Source Value Transformer within the address mapping.

[image]

However, it appears my delimiter of \r\n is being encoded somehow, so instead of line breaks i get

`Address1\r\n\City\r\nState\r\nZip`

Any way I can map multiple fields into separate lines in a multi-line textbox?

I probably need to write my own reader to transform the value - but I wanted to check if there was a better way first.

I'm also going through the framework code - and i don't see where the value is actually encoded - so i'm concerned if i DO write a custom value reader my value will just end up encoded as well - so i think i need to find that FIRST so i know how to avoid it

For example, The ootb value reader is only this

```
public virtual ReadResult Read(object source, DataAccessContext context)
{
  if (source == null)
    return ReadResult.PositiveResult((object) null, DateTime.Now);
  ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
  if (collection == null)
    return ReadResult.NegativeResult(DateTime.Now);
  List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
  foreach (object obj in (IEnumerable) collection)
    objectList.Add(obj);
  return ReadResult.PositiveResult((object) string.Join<object>(this.Separator, (IEnumerable<object>) objectList), DateTime.Now);
}
```

So it seems that simply writing my own value reader to add line breaks is pointless as unless I figure out how to avoid the encoding.

UPDATE -Solution from Vlad below was it.  Below is the updated converter in case it helps others.

```
protected override ConvertResult<IValueReader> ConvertSupportedItem(ItemModel source)
{
    return this.PositiveResult((IValueReader)new CollectionToStringValueReader()
    {
            Separator = PreserveLineBreaks(this.GetStringValue(source, FieldNameSeparator))
    });
 }

private string PreserveLineBreaks(string separator)
{
    var unescapedSeparator = Regex.Unescape(separator);

    return unescapedSeparator == Environment.NewLine ? unescapedSeparator : separator;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but as far as I know, Multi-Line Text field cannot does not convert the `\r\n` as a break line. You might need to change the field type to Rich Text or add a custom Multi-Line Text field

Comment: It's encoded in CollectionToStringValueConverter. Converter reads data from field and its value "\\r\\n".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When converter gets separator value from field its value is "\\r\\n" and at the end your result is "Address1\r\n\City\r\nState\r\nZip".

Just add your custom converter.

```
    [SupportedIds("[YOUR TEMPLATE ID]")]
public class CollectionToStringNewLIneConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<IValueReader>
{
    public CollectionToStringNewLIneConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
    protected override ConvertResult<IValueReader> ConvertSupportedItem(ItemModel source)
    {
        var reader = new CollectionToStringValueReader
        {
            Separator = Environment.NewLine
        };
        return PositiveResult(reader);
    }
}
```

Or still use the same template with Separator field but with custom converter to enescape separator value.

```
[SupportedIds("{03639AB3-5C4B-45E3-AE4E-A41EF33F3E06}")]
public class CustomUnescapeCollectionToStringValueReaderConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<IValueReader>
{
    public const string FieldNameSeparator = "Separator";
    public CustomUnescapeCollectionToStringValueReaderConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
    protected override ConvertResult<IValueReader> ConvertSupportedItem(ItemModel source)
    {
        var reader = new CollectionToStringValueReader
        {
            Separator = Regex.Unescape(this.GetStringValue(source, FieldNameSeparator))
        };
        return PositiveResult(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad!  That was it.  FYI - only change I made to your suggestion was just to limit the unescaping to the linebreaks - to lessen the chance of unintended consequences.

I'll edit the question to include the updated code.